# ObjC: restrict id to some types

Tags: objective-c, types

In Objective-C, is it possible to restrict `id` to just a few types? I want to write a method having an `id` parameter, but this method applies only to some ObjC types: using `id` could lead to runtime errors. Is there any LLVM convention or something like that?

Comment: If this **few types** implement some `protocol`, you can write `id<SomeInterface>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a generic Objective-C object pointer, ie it means *any object*.

The only way you could restrict the type would be using protocols:

```
id <myProtocol>
```

Therefore, in this way, you point to any object which adopts the `myProtocol` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're dealing with objects, you can ask for it's class:

```
id anId;

if ([anId isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd like to get a compile-time error/warning if an inappropriate type is passed...

Comment: @user732274 using a protocol, you can get a warning, and you can turn this warning into an error by using the `-Werror` compiler flag.

Answer (score 1):

"restricting" `id` is not something Objective-C has. Anyways, if you pass an object of which the type doesn't match the type specified in the method declaration, you would only get a warning and not a compiler error (unless you compile using `-Werror`), so the compiler can't really *prevent* you from doing this.

Yes, this is runtime-error-prone, but that's how Objective-C works. One thing you *should* do is **documenting** which types are accepted.

One thing you *can* do is **checking the type at runtime**, either by using the `isKindOfClass:` or `isMemeberOfClass:` methods of `NSObject`. Also, if there are a common set of messages the object should respond to, you can wrap them into a protocol and require an expression of type `id <MyProtocol>`.